# creating input field in form generated by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

[js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5L17q0th/)

I have a drop zone on a page which shows photos successfully uploaded to server once they are added to the drop zone. each photo has a class called uploaded holding each separate photo inside of it. Once the image is uploaded I need each photo to have an input field showing next to it allowing a user to add tags to each photo. Once they type tags which will be comma delimited in the input field they will be able to click submit. At that point the function called

```
addTags()
```

will be called and the tags will be added to the photo based on the file name. 
I am having trouble figuring out the most professional way to do this,

I was thinking of creating a form with all hidden fields adding the name of the field with a value holding the file name. This would be easy to obtain the file name and tags with ajax. Please show me how something like this would be done professionally.

This is the JS which allows and loops through showing the uploaded files,

```
 // Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
    $('#upload').fileupload({

        // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
        dropZone: $('#drop'),

        // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
        // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
        add: function (e, data) {

            var tpl = $('<li class="working uploaded"><input type="text" value="0" data-width="48" data-height="48"'+
                ' data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" /><p></p><span></span></li>');

        // Append the file name and file size      
            tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name)
                         .append('<i>' + formatFileSize(data.files[0].size) + '</i>');

            // Add the HTML to the UL element
            data.context = tpl.appendTo(ul);

            // Initialize the knob plugin
            tpl.find('input').knob();

            // Listen for clicks on the cancel icon
            tpl.find('span').click(function(){

                if(tpl.hasClass('working')){
                    jqXHR.abort();
                }

                tpl.fadeOut(function(){
                    tpl.remove();
                });

            });

            // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
            var jqXHR = data.submit();
        },
```

So the filename is returned for each file that is uploaded in the drop zone like this,

```
tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name)
```

Now how would I create form in this JS function adding the name to each hidden form field for each file uploaded and add a text input field allowing entry of tags for the pictures.

essentially i'm looking for a way to add a form like this,

```
 <form onSubmit="addTags();return false;">
<input type="hidden" name="imgName" value="var imgName" id="imgName">
<input type="text" name="tags" palceholder="add tags seperated by ," id="tags">
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Add Tags" class="submit" id="adTags"/>
                    </form>
```

addTags() function

```
function addTags(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'data/add_tags.php',
        data: "&tag_type_id=" + $('#tag_type_id').val() + "&tag_target_name=" + $('#tag_target_name').val() +
            "&tag_target_url=" + $('#tag_target_url').val() + "&tags=" + $('#tags').val(),    
                success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response === 'error'){
                        $('.messageText').empty()
                    $('.messageImage').empty()
                    $('.messageText').append('Please add tags seperated by commas');
                $(".messageImage").append('<img src="images/error.png" height="50" width="50">');
                $('.message').slideDown(400).delay(10000).fadeOut(400)   
            }
            else {
                    $('.messageText').empty()
                    $('.messageImage').empty()
                    $('.messageText').append('Your tags have been added.');
                    $(".messageImage").append('<img src="images/success.png" height="50" width="50">');
                    $('.message').slideDown(400).delay(10000).fadeOut(400)   
            }   
       }
    });
 };

   AJAX makes call to this php function,

<?php
//Include files                 
require_once('../classes/class_login.php');

$tag_type_id = $_POST['tag_type_id'];
$tag_target_name = $_POST['tag_target_name'];
$tag_target_url = $_POST['tag_target_url'];
$tags = $_POST['tags'];

    /*** begin with some validation ***/
    if(!isset($_POST['tag_type_id'], $_POST['tag_target_name'], $_POST['tag_target_url'], $_POST['tags']))
    {
        /*** if no POST is submited ***/
        $msg = 'Please Submit a tag';
        print('error');
    }
    elseif(filter_var($_POST['tag_type_id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("min_range"=>1, "max_range"=>100)) == false)
    {
        /*** if tag is too short ***/
        $msg = 'Invalid Tag Type';
                print('error');
    }
    elseif( strlen($_POST['tag_target_url']) == 0 )
    {
        /*** if tag is too long ***/
        $msg = 'Tag target is required';
                print('error');
    }
    elseif( strlen($_POST['tags']) == 0 )
    {
        $msg = 'Tag Required';
                print('error');
    }
    elseif(  strlen($_POST['tag_target_name']) == 0 )
    {
        $msg = 'Tag Name is too short';
                print('error');
    }
    elseif( strlen($_POST['tag_target_name']) > 30 )
    {
        $msg = 'Tag Name is too long!';
                print('error');
    }
    else
    {
        /*** if we are here, all is well ***/

        $tag_type_id = filter_var($_POST['tag_type_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $tag_target_url = filter_var($_POST['tag_target_url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $tag_target_name = filter_var($_POST['tag_target_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $tags = filter_var($_POST['tags'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

            addTags($tag_type_id, $tag_target_name, $tag_target_url, $tags);

            $msg = 'Tag Type Added!';
                    print('success');
        }

?>
```

php function is defined in a class like this,

```
function addTags($tag_type_id, $tag_target_name, $tag_target_url, $tags){

        /*** explode the tag string ***/
            $tag_array = explode(',', $tags);

            /*** loop of the tags array ***/
            foreach( $tag_array as $tag_name )
            {
                /*** insert tag into tags table ***/
                $tag_name = strtolower(trim($tag_name));

                $databaseQuery = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tags (tag_name ) VALUES ('$tag_name')";
                //Execute database query
                executeDatabase($databaseQuery);

                /*** get the tag ID from the db ***/
                $databaseQuery  = "SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_name='$tag_name'";
                $result = executeDatabase($databaseQuery);
                $tag_id = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                /*** now insert the target ***/
                $databaseQuery = "INSERT INTO tag_targets
                    (tag_id, tag_target_name, tag_target_url, tag_type_id)
                    VALUES
                    ('$tag_id', '$tag_target_name', '$tag_target_url', '$tag_type_id')";
                executeDatabase($databaseQuery);
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide Fiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5L17q0th/ so to be clear, once someone uploads the images. I want them to be able to add tags associated with each image. then when they want to submit the tags a function called addTags() would be called.

Comment: Wouldn't It be better to save the tags at the same time as the photo is saved in the server. So under the drop box you would put the tags input and the "Upload" button would save the photo and the tags under the same request.

Comment: They can upload multiple images at the same time. So if you drag 10 photots in to the drop box I need the user to be able to add ags to each image seperatley.

Comment: Your fiddle seems incomplete. Please add required libraries..

Comment: I edited this post and added all my code. Youdrop photos in drop zone. then to add tags i need a inut field which adds the name of each file to hidden input field holding the name of each file name. THen a input field which takes tags, on submit call the addTags function which calls php function which is defined in class and makes entry in to database.

Comment: In reality. all I am asking is the first function of java script which shows each name of files uploaded. How can I turn each name in to a var and add it to a form adding a new input field which would take tags.

Comment: to make this easy, each name of each file uploaded is in here,  tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name) how can i create form and add the name held in this  tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name) in to each name value ina  hidden input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, you can create elements, set their attributes and append them to the DOM using [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute), and [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).  Example:

```
var myNewElement= document.createElement("input");
myNewElement.setAttribute("id","new_element_id");
myNewElement.setAttribute("class","new_element_class");
myNewElement.setAttribute("name","new_element_name");
document.getElementById("desired_parent").appendChild(myNewElement);
```

Note that there is an alternative/complementary method to this.  If you're creating a lot of similar, complex elements (e.g. you have an 'image descriptor' box that has some text elements, the input field, a few divs, etc.), you can have a hidden element on the page with all those elements, clone it, and use this method to modify part of it and put it where you want.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. This kind of makes sense to me. Would you mind adding my code to this example. For example if there were 8 pictures dropped in the drop zone I would need the name of each file to be the name value and then a text input field to show for users to add tags. Then I submit regardless of how many files were uploaded we would obtain tags for all of them if they were filled in.

Comment: Also once I was to add everything to the inputs on submit can I call the other JS function the same way.